# Sparse Matrices in Java

Tags: java, matrix, getter-setter

Sparse matrices are matrices whose elements are predominantly zero. The codes below use an ArrayList of LinkedLists to implement a sparse matrice. It defines a class Element to store the column number and value for an element. Each row is represented by a LinkedList of Elements with non-zero values only. Few, if any, rows are all zeros and so the ArrayList is used to store a LinkedList for every row in ascending row order.

```
class Element { 
  public int column; 
  public int value; }

public class SparseMatrix { 
  private int mRows; // Number of rows 
  private int mCols; // Number of columns 
  private ArrayList<LinkedList<Element>> mMatrix;
```

1) How do I make use of a getter with parameters (int r, int c) which presents a certain row and column number to retrieve the value within that row and column of the matrix?

2) How do I make use of a setter with parameters (int r, int c, int v), to set the value at row r and column c to v? (Note: If node is not already there, a new node must be created. If v is zero, remove the node.)

Please correct me if I am wrong, but to get the total number of rows and columns respectively for the matrix, I would do:

```
get(int r, int c) {
    int rowSize = mMatrix.length;
    int colSize = mMatrix[0].length;
    }
```

However, I am unsure of how to make use of this subsequently.

Comment: Q1: how would you check if mMatrix has enough rows for 'r'?  If not, how do you "grow" it?  Q2: how would you get ahold of the specific LinkedList for a given row? Q3: having the linked list for a row, how would you scan through to check if there's already an element for column `c`?  If you find one, how would you go about getting/setting its value?  If you don't, how would you go about making a new one and adding it to the list? ... posting the attempt you've made for at least a few of these steps should improve people's desire to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just drop the code here with some elementary comments. You should be able to adjust it according to your needs.
I wont use `class Element` since its holding an int. Significance of value `column` is irrelevant.

```
private static int mRows; // Number of rows 
private static int mCols; // Number of columns 
private static final ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> mMatrix = new ArrayList<>();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    mRows = 7; //example
    mCols = 4; //example

     //init your matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < mRows; i++) { //add new row 7 times
        mMatrix.add(new LinkedList<>());
        for (int j = 0; j < mCols; j++) {
            mMatrix.get(i).add(0); // add Integer with value 0 (4 times)
        }
    }

    //test
    setValue(5, 3, 159);
    System.out.println(getValue(5, 3));

}

public static void setValue(int r, int c, Integer v) {
    //before call be sure that r < mRows and c < mCols
    mMatrix.get(r).set(c, v); //replaces existing Integer
}

public static Integer getValue(int r, int c) {
    //before call be sure that r < mRows and c < mCols
    return mMatrix.get(r).get(c);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably not use lists, I would use a `Map<Point,T>` behind the scenes.

Untested code:

```
interface Matrix<T> {
    public T get(Point p);
    public void put(Point p, T v);
}

class SparseMatrix<T extends Number> implements Matrix<T> {
    Map<Point,T> map = new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    public T get(Point p) {
        return map.get(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(Point p, T v) {
        if ( v.doubleValue() == 0.0) {
            // Any zeros get removed.
            map.remove(p);
        } else {
            map.put(p, v);
        }
    }
}

class Point {
    final int row;
    final int col;

    Point(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Point point = (Point) o;

        if (row != point.row) return false;
        return col == point.col;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = row;
        result = 31 * result + col;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever, but remember the memory overhead for HashMap,